# Trying to centre some image divs. What is the best way? DIV or Table? Have some code attached

Tags: html

I am trying to centre 3 image icons. I have chosen DIVs as opposed to TABLE tags as the more modern approach, but having some issue with it, like I cannot get it to centre.

Here is the code:

```
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="">
            <div><img src="../../Content/images/Image1.png" alt=""/></div>
            <div>Image1</div>
        </div>
        <div style="">
            <div><img src="../../Content/images/Image2.png" alt=""/></div>
            <div>Image2</div>    
        </div>
        <div style="">
            <div><img src="../../Content/images/Image3.png" alt=""/></div>
            <div>Image3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have a strange feeling the solution is simple. I did try "float:left" to get the icons to clump to together, but then could not get the "clump" to centre.

Basically need:

```
Image1  Image2  Image3
    Image4  Image5
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the -1 for???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using inline-blocks, also, you don't need to wrap EVERYTHING inside div tags :P, you can also try with span tags instead of those divs.

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <img src="../../Content/images/Image1.png" alt=""/>
        %br
        Image1
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <img src="../../Content/images/Image2.png" alt=""/>
        %br
        Image2    
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <img src="../../Content/images/Image3.png" alt=""/>
        %br
        Image3
    </div>
</div>
```